EasyPHP devserver 17.0 don't works in Win11 - Error (0xc000007b)
I've always used EasyPHP without any problems, but recently I had to format the laptop and lost everything. I installed Windows 11 and EasyPHP, but it gives error messages like (0xc000007b). I have already tried several alternatives found on Google, such as installing and reinstalling DirectX,.NET and Visual C++, in many versions but nothing goes right. What to do?
Whenever I open the control panel, the message (0xc000007b) appears. I'm using EasyPHP Devserver 17.0
